# Swift MessageKit issues

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, messagekit

Here to show the image after installing MessageKit and the problems I am currently having with it. Maybe it's my pod file that is the problem but the MessageKit has issues in it. It looks like inside the MessageKit pod file some code needs to be updates from what it is showing me in Xcode after trying to build it. I have been cleaning and building my project. My project was working before installing MessageKit.

```
 pod 'Firebase'
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Auth'
 pod 'Firebase/Storage'
 pod 'Firebase/Database'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
 pod 'Firebase/Crash'
 pod 'GoogleSignIn'
 pod 'Bolts'
 pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
 pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
 pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
 pod 'TwitterKit'
 pod 'TwitterCore'
 pod 'SnapKit'
 pod 'Alamofire'
 pod 'SwiftyJSON'
 pod 'SDWebImage'
 pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage'
 pod 'SVProgressHUD'
 pod 'SWRevealViewController'
 pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
 pod 'IGListKit'
 pod 'InstagramKit/UICKeyChainStore'
 pod 'InstagramKit'
 pod 'Reusable'
 pod 'OAuthSwift'
 pod 'AFNetworking'
 pod 'MBProgressHUD'
 pod 'Fabric'
 pod 'Crashlytics'
 pod 'OneSignal'
 pod 'BottomPopup'
 pod 'Kingfisher'
 pod 'MessageKit'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'MessageKit'
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
          end
      end
   end
   end

end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'OneSignal'
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using the latest version of MessageKit which is 2.0. This version is only compatible with **Swift 4.2**

So if you use **Swift 4.2** remove this

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'MessageKit'
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
          end
      end
   end
end
```

If use MessageKit with **Swift 4.0** or **3.0** you need to use the version 1.0 of MessageKit. So your pod file would be like that

```
pod 'MessageKit', '~> 1.0.0'
```

I hope it solve your problem

Comment: just change the 4.0 to 4.2?

Comment: I think this project is may be in Swift 4.0 so he have to use MessageKit 1.0 or upgrade to Swift 4.2 to use the latest one

Comment: I am using the current version of everything. My project is completely up to date. Should I remove everything underneath "post_install"?

Comment: If your project is in Swift 4.2 yes remove it

Comment: Ok, I removed it. Should I still put "~> '1.0'" there and do a pod install?

Comment: If your project is not in Swift 4.2 yes. If your project is in Swift 4.2 do not do that

Comment: I had reinstalled my pods with just "pod 'MessageKit'" but am still getting the same errors

Comment: Have you remove the post_install part ?

Comment: So if you still have this error, your project is in Swift 4.0 may be

Comment: So you have to use messagekit 1.0

Comment: Yes, maybe I am not reinstalling my pods correctly?

Comment: Which version of swift are you using ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183818/discussion-between-julien-kode-and-lukas-bimba).